# Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java"

Tags: maven, java

Учусь писать сервлеты на Java, пользуюсь помощью одного хабрахабровца (не кидаю ссылки ибо не знаю, можно ли тут это). 
Но вопрос вот в чем, я стараюсь собрать проект maven, а у меня пишет ошибку как в заголовке

`Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java"`

Переменные среды установлены и еще самое главное у меня jdk1.8.0._77.

Как можно избавиться от такой ошибки?

Пользуюсь Intellij IDE

Comment: А вы проверьте путь, на который ругается IDE у вас. Раз уж версия jdk другая, то и путь наверное будет "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java"

Comment: Так у меня совсем нет jdk 73 а она ссылается на неё.
Наверное в самой IDE нужно где указать путь к фактическому расположению jdk?

Comment: Ну значит надо указать ту, которая есть у Вас. Посмотрите, что использует Ваша IDE. Наверное как-то так https://risik.info/?p=444

Comment: Спасибо) оказалось очень легко))